# Online database for unity game for balancing purposes

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

Looking on good advice what technology to use for online database for unity game: have about 50 characters in a game and want to change their characteristics (about 10 per each) online in a built version of a game for balancing purposes. Need some stable, simple solution for novice. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create yourself a C# console application to serve you as a server?
There you can integrate MySQL with ease.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll try the mysql option. But maybe there are some off the shelf solutions? Imho it is very common need for developers to have online database with simple  customizable interface for data storage and editing...also for balancing game...

Answer (score 0):

Literally *anything* will work for something as simple as this.

Unless you need a database for other purposes, I'd probably skip the database entirely and just have a static .csv file served over HTTP that the game just downloads as needed.